# HTML5 doctype breaking layout of niceforms. Is there a solution?

Tags: css, html, niceforms

I would like to use niceforms ([demo](http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/demo/niceforms.html)) on my website but HTML5 breaks the design (the corners of text areas shift).

Since I would rather not rely on the "Almost Standards" mode that I suppose makes it look correct with XHTML 1.0 Transitional, I hope someone can tell me how I can make it work with HTML5.

Aside from the demo and the [CSS file](https://github.com/emblematiq/Niceforms/blob/master/niceforms-default.css), I don't think there's anything relevant to this that I could share.
One literally just has to change the doctype of the demo and everything shifts a couple of pixels vertically, breaking selection box, text area and that upload box.

Comment: We need a dome of the broken HTML5 version as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS wrote in DEMO is CSS2.
I recommend you using CSS3 with HTML 5.
Text area problems are:

- using Table.
- Textarea surrounded with divs to show rounded corners. You should use **border-radius**

Comment: Hm... I thought that HTML5 and CSS2 would grant me best compatibility with both old and new browsers. But I suppose I should stick with XHTML 1.0 Transitional and CSS2 for now and hope browsers will still render it correctly in a couple of years.
Thanks for the suggestion though, would have been a nice solution!

Comment: HTML5 and CSS2 are compatible.. But HTML5 is not fully compatible with Tables in layout.. Tables now limited to be used. Since CSS2 tables are not used for layouts. Divs, ULs are used instead.